# ERROR! A malformed role declaration was encountered

Tags: ansible

When, I execute a playbook, I got below error:

```
➜  ansible ansible-playbook site.yml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! A malformed role declaration was encountered.

The error appears to be in '/Users/channa/random_poc/ansible/site.yml': line 2, column 4, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
 - name: "Play 1"
   ^ here
```

I have checked and tried changing my own my playbook, `site.xml`, by referring some example found online. But, nothing seems to be working out and I am always getting the same error.

Here's my playbook `site.xml`:

```yaml
---
 - name: "Play 1"
   hosts: localhost
   roles:
      — myuser
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yo run a playbook, you have to use the command `ansible-playbook` and not the command `ansible`, which is for ad-hoc commands. > `ansible-playbook site.yml`.

Comment: I meant _"To run"_, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue, with your "-" character.

The following works:

```
---
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - myuser
```

Note the difference, between:

```
  — myuser
```

And

```
  - myuser
```

And as suggested by β.εηοιτ.βε, execute with:

```
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook
```

Comment: hey, this works..thanks..I just copied -pasted your line. sorry,I can't understand the difference much. I'm very new to ansible :D